# The meaning of the sentence

Tags: meaning

> 一月一日から**一月七日、または**一月十五日まで、新しい年のお祝いをします。

I would understand this sentence if the part in bold was omitted: New Year is celebrated from January 1 to January 15. What is "一月七日、または” for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`または` means `or`.

So, the sentence means `New Year is celebrated from January 1 to January 7 or January 15.`

> 一月一日から一月七日、または一月十五日まで、新しい年のお祝いをします。

Other examples:

> アメリカ、または日本に行きます。

I'll go to the US, or Japan.

> このテストはスミス先生、またはジョンソン先生に渡してください。

Please hand this test to Smith-sensei, or Johnson-sensei.